# Как найти нужную таблицу?

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql

В таблице owner есть свойство: `filts VARCHAR(255) ARRAY`.
В таблице track есть свойство: `filt: VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL`.

Нужно найти такую таблицу owner, чтобы хоть один элемент из массива `filts` совпадал с пришедшим с клиента `filt`.

Я пытался сделать что-то типа того:

```js
const queryForFindOwner = `SELECT * FROM owner WHERE filts && ARRAY[$1]`;
const findOwner = await db.query(queryForFindOwner, [track.filt]);
```

Но не получилось

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM owner WHERE $1 = ANY (filts)
```